# Play 2.1(scala) - How to write Format[T] for scala enumeration case class

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

This question is related to the following two questions.

We wanted to use enumeration in a model in our play 2.1 application so we found the following question
[How to write Reads[T] and Writes[T] in scala Enumeration (play framework 2.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488639/how-to-write-readst-and-writest-in-scala-enumeration-play-framework-2-1)

It's then mentioned that using case class in scala is better than scala enumeration. So we found the following question

[Case objects vs Enumerations in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898932/case-classes-vs-enumerations-in-scala)

How do we write json format for the case class enumeration suggested above then? Namely the case class enumeration is like

```
trait Enum[A] {
  trait Value { self: A => }
  val values: List[A]
}

sealed trait Currency extends Currency.Value
object Currency extends Enum[Currency] {
  case object EUR extends Currency
  case object GBP extends Currency
  val values = List(EUR, GBP)
}
```

We are new to Play/scala especially its functional JSON api. I tried to write  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Other implementation

```
object EnumFormat {
  implicit def jsonReads[A](enum: Enumeration): Reads[A] = new Reads[A] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[A] = json match {
      case JsString(s) => {
        try {
          JsSuccess(enum.withName(s).asInstanceOf[A])
        } catch {
          case _: NoSuchElementException =>
            JsError(s"Enumeration expected of type: '${enum.getClass}', but it does not contain '$s'")
        }
      }
      case _ => JsError("String value expected")
    }
  }
  implicit def jsonWrites[A]: Writes[A] = new Writes[A] {
    def writes(v: A): JsValue = JsString(v.toString)
  }
  implicit def jsonFormat[A](enum: Enumeration): Format[A] = {
    Format(jsonReads(enum), jsonWrites)
  }
}

object DeviceStatus extends Enumeration {

  val UNKNOWN = DeviceStatusType(0x0)
  val REGISTERED = DeviceStatusType(0x1)
  val NO_REGISTERED = DeviceStatusType(0x1000)

  case class DeviceStatusType(code: Int) extends Val(code) {

    import play.api.libs.json._
    import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

    implicit def valueTo(v: Value): DeviceStatusType = v.asInstanceOf[DeviceStatusType]
  }

  implicit val jsonFormat: Format[DeviceStatus.DeviceStatusType] = EnumFormat.jsonFormat(DeviceStatus)
}
```

Comment: The question is not about implementing the typeclasses for`scala.Enumeration`, the OP links to another question which is about exactly that. This question is about implementing them for a sealed type hierarchy.