# Create Reads/Writes for Java Enum without Field

Tags: json, scala, playframework, enums

With the Play Framework's JSON library, how can I create a `Reads` and `Writes` for a Java enum without fields?

`public enum EnumNoFields {
    RED,
    WHITE,
    BLUE
}`

```
implicit val EnumNoFieldsReads: Reads[EnumNoFields] = ?
implicit val EnumNoFieldsWrites: Writes[EnumNoFields] = ?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write Reads\[T\] and Writes\[T\] in scala Enumeration (play framework 2.1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488639/how-to-write-readst-and-writest-in-scala-enumeration-play-framework-2-1)

Comment: No, this question is about Java enums used in scala. The other is about scala's own Enumeration class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I simply made use of [Enum#name](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name%28%29).

```
  implicit val EnumNoFieldsReads: Reads[EnumNoFields] =
    (JsPath \ "displayValue").read[String].map{x: String => EnumNoFields.valueOf(x)}

  implicit val EnumNoFieldsWrites: Writes[EnumNoFields] =
    (JsPath \ "displayValue").write[String].contramap{x:EnumNoFields => x.name}
```

Comment: If I were to answer this question today, I'd recommend my younger self to look at https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum!

Answer (score 6):

A generic solution would look like this:

```
def javaEnumFormat[E <: Enum[E] : ClassTag] = new Format[E] {
  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[E] = json.validate[String] match {
    case JsSuccess(value, _) => try {
      val clazz = implicitly[ClassTag[E]].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[E]]
      JsSuccess(Enum.valueOf(clazz, value))
    } catch {
      case _: IllegalArgumentException => JsError("enumeration.unknown.value")
    }
    case JsError(_) => JsError("enumeration.expected.string")
  }

  override def writes(o: E): JsValue = JsString(o.toString)
}
```

which you can use like this:

`implicit val enumNoFieldsFormat = javaEnumFormat[EnumNoFields]`