# Error in json serialization in Scala with Play2

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.3

i have following three case classes

```
case  class  Delete(var deleteStatus : DeleteStatus , var deleteReason : DeleteReason) // DeleteStatus and DeleteReason are enums

case class Message(val uuid: Int ,val subject : String, val body : String, var awt : Int,val dateTime : LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(), delete : Delete)

case class Inbox( val uuid : Int,var messageList : ListBuffer[Message] )
```

i want to serialize them to Json and but i am not sure how should i do this

i have tried it like this

```
def writedelete(delete: Delete) = Json.obj(
      "deleteStatus" ->  delete.getDeleteStatusInt.toString, 
      "deleteReason" -> delete.getDeleteReasonInt.toString
    )

      def writeMessage(mgs : Message)= Json.obj(
        "uuid" -> mgs.getUuid ,
        "subject" -> mgs.getSubject,
        "body" -> mgs.getBody,
        "awt" -> mgs.getAwt,
        "datetime" -> mgs.getdateTime.toString,
        "delete" -> mgs.delete
      )



    def writeInbox(inbox : Inbox)= Json.obj(
        "uuid" -> inbox.getUuid,
        "mgslist" -> Seq(inbox.getMessageList)
     )
```

but it gives following error on `mgs.delete` in  `writeMessage`  and `mgslist` in `writeInbox`

```
type mismatch; found : models.UserNotifications.MailMessages.Delete 
 required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper

type mismatch; found : 
 Seq[scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[models.UserNotifications.MailMessages.Message]] 
 required: play.api.libs.json.Json.JsValueWrapper
```

please guide me how can i get get rid off it

and also is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Json.obj(...)` to construct a JSON object various implicit conversions are available to convert common types (e.g. `String`, `Int`) to their JSON wrapper types (`JsString`, `JsNumber`). The problem with your code is there are no implicit conversions available to convert your `Delete` and `Message` types to JSON. One option would be to use your explicit conversion functions directly, e.g:

```
"delete" -> writeDelete(mgs.delete)
```

and (using `Json.arr(...)` to construct a JSON array):

```
"msglist" -> Json.arr(inbox.getMessageList.toSeq.map(writeMessage): _*)
```

---

However, the more idiomatic way to do this would be to use the [JSON Inception macros](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJsonInception) to automatically generate (implicit) serializers for your types.

Simplifying slightly, this would look something like this:

```
case class Delete(deleteStatus: DeleteStatus, deleteReason: DeleteReason)
object Delete {
  implicit val _format = Json.format[Delete]
}

case class Message(uuid: Int, subject: String, body: String, awt: Int, dateTime: LocalDateTime, delete: Delete)
object Message {
  implicit val _format = Json.format[Message]
}

case class Inbox(uuid: Int, messageList: ListBuffer[Message])
object Inbox {
  implicit val _format = Json.format[Message]
}
```

You should now be able to automatically serialize (and de-serialize) your `Delete`, `Message`, and `Inbox` objects using `Json.toJson(thing)` because it will find an implicit [`Format`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Format) object (a combined [`Reads`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Reads) and [`Writes`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.Writes)) on the companion object of each custom type.

**One complication here** is that your case classes contain enums; if they're Scala enumerations see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15489179/285374) for how to convert them. I leave that as an exercise for the reader.