# Not able to parse Map with Enum to Json in Play Scala

Tags: json, scala, enums, playframework-2.0

We use `Scala 2.11.8` and `Play framework 2.5.8`

Data to work with can be as simple as that:

```
object EnumA extends Enumeration {
  type EnumA = Value
  val ONE, TWO, THREE = Value
}

case class NoWork(data: Map[EnumA.Value, String] = Map.empty)
```

And what I want to archive is to be able to parse the `NoWork` class to `Json`. I know that to it requires providing an implicit formatter for `Enumeration`.

I have found this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15489179/1549135 and applied it.

The companion object providing those implicits looks as follows:

```
object NoWork {
  implicit val enumAFormat = EnumUtils.enumFormat(EnumA)

  implicit val jsonModelFormat = Json.format[NoWork]
}
```

And it always fails with an error:

```
error: No implicit format for Map[EnumA.Value,String] available.
         implicit val jsonModelFormat = Json.format[NoWork]
                                                   ^
```

What is the issue?

I have tested and changing the `data` type to `Map[String, String]` allows for serialization. The `Enum` on its own is serializable too, so now - how to fix the `Map` with `Enum` type?

Thanks!

**Edit**

As Pamu's answer

```
implicit val writes = new Writes[Map[EnumA.Value, String]] {
     override def writes(o: Map[EnumA.Value, String]): JsValue = Json.toJson(o.map { case (a, b) => Json.parse(s"""{${Json.toJson(a)}:${Json.toJson(b)}}""")}.toList)
}
```

would clearly work for **this** situation, I would actually need a generic solution for other `Map[Enum, T]` that I could use in whole application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With colleague we have prepared a generic class that provides JSON serialization for `Map[E <: Enum[E], T]` type.

The `Enum` type is always converted to `String` as it is required for `JsObject` `key`. The other parameter is generic and is converted using the `implicit format: Format[T]`

```
import play.api.data.validation.ValidationError
import play.api.libs.json._    
import scala.util.{Failure, Success, Try}

class MapEnumFormat[E <: Enum[E], T](valueOf: (String => E))(implicit format: Format[T]) extends Format[Map[E, T]] {

  override def writes(o: Map[E, T]): JsValue = {
    JsObject(o.map { case (a, b) => (a.name, Json.toJson(b)) })
  }

  override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[Map[E, T]] = {
    val result = Try(json.as[Map[String, T]].map {
      case (key, value) =>
        valueOf(key) -> value
    })

    result match {
      case Success(status) =>
        JsSuccess(status)
      case Failure(th) =>
        JsError(ValidationError(s"Error while serializing $json: $th"))
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that it is mandatory for Json keys to be strings.

Following code works

```
Json.toJson(Map("mon" -> EnumA.MON))
```

Following code does not work because key for valid Json should always be string. Here the key is `EnumA.Value` which is not `String`.

```
scala> Json.toJson(Map(EnumA.MON -> "mon"))
    <console>:19: error: No Json serializer found for type scala.collection.immutable.Map[EnumA.Value,String]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
           Json.toJson(Map(EnumA.MON -> "mon"))
```

But if you want it work as expected provide a `writes`

```
 implicit val writes = new Writes[Map[EnumA.Value, String]] {
      override def writes(o: Map[EnumA.Value, String]): JsValue = Json.toJson(o.map { case (a, b) => Json.parse(s"""{${Json.toJson(a)}:${Json.toJson(b)}}""")}.toList)
    }
```

now following code works

```
 Json.toJson(Map(EnumA.MON -> "hello"))
```

You can declare format for `EnumA` as following

```
  object EnumA extends Enumeration {
    val MON = Value("monday")
    val TUE = Value("Tuesday")

    implicit val format = new Format[EnumA.Value] {
      override def writes(o: EnumA.Value): JsValue = Json.toJson(o.toString)
      override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[EnumA.Value] = json.validate[String].map(EnumA.withName(_))
    }
  }
```

**Scala REPL output**

```
scala>       object EnumA extends Enumeration {
     |         val MON = Value("monday")
     |         val TUE = Value("Tuesday")
     |
     |         implicit val format = new Format[EnumA.Value] {
     |           override def writes(o: EnumA.Value): JsValue = Json.toJson(o.toString)
     |           override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[EnumA.Value] = json.validate[String].map(EnumA.withName(_))
     |         }
     |       }
defined object EnumA

scala> Json.toJson(EnumA.MON)
res0: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = "monday"

scala> (Json.parse("""{"a": "monday"}""") \ "a").validate[EnumA.Value]
res7: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[EnumA.Value] = JsSuccess(monday,)

scala> (Json.parse("""{"a": "monday"}""") \ "a").validate[EnumA.Value].get
res10: EnumA.Value = monday

scala> Json.toJson(Map("mon" -> EnumA.MON))
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"mon":"monday"}

scala> Json.toJson(Map(EnumA.MON -> "mon"))
<console>:19: error: No Json serializer found for type scala.collection.immutable.Map[EnumA.Value,String]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
       Json.toJson(Map(EnumA.MON -> "mon"))

scala> implicit val writes = new Writes[Map[EnumA.Value, String]] {
     |       override def writes(o: Map[EnumA.Value, String]): JsValue = Json.toJson(o.map { case (a, b) => Json.parse(s"""{${Json.toJson(a)}:${Json.toJson(b)}}""")}.toList)
     |     }
writes: play.api.libs.json.Writes[Map[EnumA.Value,String]] = $anon$1@65aebb67

scala>  Json.toJson(Map(EnumA.MON -> "hello"))
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"monday":"hello"}]
```

Comment: But as I told, the `Enum` works fine. But `Map[Enum, String]` does not.

Comment: @Atais ... edited the answer ... with what you are expecting .. Please check. Hope this helps

Comment: but... you got the exact same error I originally asked about

Comment: @Atais  ... please check the answer .... I gave the reason why this happens. The reason is explained in the edited answer

Comment: @Atais `Map[String, CustomType]` can be converted to Json but `Map[CustomType, String]` cannot be converted to Json directly because valid json always has string as key.

Comment: I understand the reason. Now I need a converter/implicit/whatever to fix it.

Comment: @Atais ... Now it works .... i have edited the answer . PLease check .. Is this want you wanted ?

Comment: This is nearly what I wanted. I will try on my own as well, but I would like the implicit to be generic for every `Enum` and `Map[Enum, X]`